# AngularJS animate data bind and change with timer

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, timeout, ng-animate

I would like make animation to data binding, but only when it change.

I would like make it with Javascript and I get it with ng-repeat and ng-class and addClass, removeClass for images, but now I want make it with a tittle.

This is working with ng-repeat, ng-class:

```
<div id="product-images" ng-repeat="img in producto.imagenes">
  <img  ng-src="{{img.url}}"
        ng-class="{active: mainImageUrl==img.url}"
        class="producto img-responsive">
</div>
```

In my controller I have $timeout that change mainImageurl and I have animation() with return function for addClass: and removeClass: (this is working fine).

What directive do you recomend me to do the same but only with tittle or paragraph? I can not find how to do this.

My miniproject is in angular 1.2

Thanks in advanced.